# Problems using catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin, p2os, p2os-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a super ROS noob, started recently. So here's what I've done.
I created a workspace at a directory called 1-RoShop. At this directory's src folder I placed the P2os stack, I ran "cd .." and "catkin_make", It gave me this:
The truth is that I don't really know if I'm performing a third-party package install correctly.

```
Base path: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop
Source space: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/src
Build space: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/build
Devel space: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/devel
Install space: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 6 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - liblms1xx
-- ~~  - lms1xx
-- ~~  - p2os_driver
-- ~~  - p2os_launch
-- ~~  - p2os_teleop
-- ~~  - p2os_urdf
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'liblms1xx'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(liblms1xx)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'lms1xx'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(lms1xx)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'p2os_driver'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(p2os/p2os_driver)
CMake Error at /home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/devel/share/diagnostic_updater/cmake/diagnostic_updaterConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'diagnostic_updater' specifies
  '/home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/src/diagnostic_updater/include'
  as an include dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an
  absolute directory nor in
  '/home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/src/diagnostic_updater//home/gabriel/Dropbox/1-UFAM/1-PROJETO_LVC/1-DESENVOLVIMENTO/5-ROS/1-RoShop/src/diagnostic_updater/include'.
  Ask the maintainer 'Austin Hendrix <namniart@gmail.com>, Brice Rebsamen
  <brice.rebsamen@gmail.com>' to fix it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package)
  p2os/p2os_driver/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: ** [cmake_check_build_system] Erro 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172804/problems-using-catkin_make/) by [RodriguesGabriel](https://answers.ros.org/users/18789/rodriguesgabriel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-06-04**:
Please update your question to preserve the format of the output in order to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have previously compiled packages in this workspace and there are still references to their components.

Assuming you're starting over I suggest `rm -rf build devel` to clean up old references to packages removed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2